# Things being read into arrays incorrectly

Tags: c, arrays

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, I did a similar problem but with reading numbers and it work, what this program is suppose to do is read in a names.txt this document contains names (last,first)

so the text has

> washington, george
>
> adams, john
>
> jefferson, thomas
> etc....

My program reads in the names but my output is not right, the output is:

> Washington, George
>
> WAdams, GJohn
>
> WAJefferson, GJThomas

So when it reads the next line it retains the first letter of the previous name?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    char first_n[70]; 
    char last_n[70];
    
    int i=0;
    FILE *oput;
    FILE *iput;
    
    iput = fopen( "names.txt","r" );
    while ( fscanf( iput,"%s %s", &last_n[i],&first_n[i] ) !=  EOF )
    {
        i++; 
        printf("%s %s\n",last_n,first_n);
    }
        
    oput=fopen("user_name_info.txt","wt"); //opens output file
    fprintf(oput, "Last\t\tFirst\n------------\t-------------\n%s\t%s\n",last_n,first_n);
    
    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You've tagged this as C++, but the code looks like pure C. Are you open to a solution that's really written in C++, or do you want C?

Comment: in C please, I didn't meant o tag it like that

Answer (score 2):

`first_n` and `last_n` are arrays of characters (i.e. think a single string)

Your `fscanf` is treating them more like you think they are an array of strings. You are reading into the string one character further along each time i.e. The first time through you put the string at offset 0, The second time through it's at offset 1...

Try this:

```
while ( fscanf( iput,"%s %s", last_n,first_n ) !=  EOF )
{
    i++; 
    printf("%s %s\n",last_n,first_n);
}
```

Your final print will only print the last "record" read. Perhaps you really did want an array of strings?
That would look a bit like this (I'm not saying this is the best way to solve the problem, but it is in the spirit of your original code...)

```
/* Limited to 20 names of 70 chars each */
char first_names[20][70]; 
char last_names[20][70];

int i=0;
FILE *oput;
FILE *iput;

iput = fopen( "names.txt","r" );
while ( fscanf( iput,"%s %s", &last_names[i],&first_names[i] ) !=  EOF )
{
    printf("%s %s\n",last_names[i],first_names[i]);
    i++;
}

oput=fopen("user_name_info.txt","wt"); //opens output file
i--; /* ensure i points to the last valid data */
while(i >= 0) { 
    fprintf(oput, "Last\t\tFirst\n------------\t-------------\n%s\t%s\n",last_names[i],first_names[i]);
    i--;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: thanks john, that fixed it right up however the second while loop fprintf statement gives me ERROR: print an invalid string
WARNING: fprintf() failed, not sure why?, i double checked the variables and made sure they matched what I declared.

Comment: the i=0 case will never be printed due to while (i > 0), you probably meant while (i>=0)

Comment: True - changed the code cos originally there was a problem at the upper end, fixed one end but not the other ;-)